# close session after the browser closed or connection got interrupted

Tags: java, session

I have gone through many post about this topic

close session after the borwser closed or conncetion got interrupted

I configure session timeout in web.xml, but one senario iam failing

a) In my application there will be cases created. this cases can be allocated to multiple users. But two users should now edit the same case. this i handled perfectly. I stored a flag in database and based on flag iam locking other user.

b) For one condition where , one user edits the case and lost the connection or browser got close unexpectedly, then his session wont be closed until specified time, but still user is not editing it. when another user tries to access it. How can i close the session and update the flag in database.

Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

First solution: Use an HttpSessionListener, which will be called when the session is about to be destroyed. Take care of removing all the locks of the user whise session is being destroyed.

Second, better solution: use optimistic locking. Allow every user to modify the data, but throw an exception if you detected that a user is modifying a version of the data that is different from the version it loaded when starting the modification. This can be done by adding a version field to the table, store it as a hidden field in the updating form, and checking it when updating:

```
update foo set ... , version = version + 1 where id = ? and version = versionSentByTheUser
```

If the update doesn't update anything, it means that the version sent by the user is not the same as the version in the database, and thus that someone else modified the data.

This optimistic locking mechanism is implemented for you by JPA, BTW.